# Exception when printing an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I know C and now trying to lean Java.

Here's a simple program which goes through a loop and changes things in "str" array. when i'm trying to print it the way I used to do in C, it works but also gives me an exception. why is that?

```
public class ReverseStringLG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] str={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
        char[] strLG={'L', 'G', 'L', 'G', 'L', 'G'};

        int i, j, k=1;

        for(j=0, i=str.length-1;i>j;j++, i--)
        {
        char tmp;
        tmp=str[j];

        if(j%2==0)
            str[j]=strLG[j];
        else
            str[j]=str[--i];

        str[i++]=tmp;
        k++;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=str.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

here's the console:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this to `for(i=0; i<str.length; i++)`

You should not be trying to access an element at index `str.length`.

Comment: why do i have to remove "="?

Comment: @VSG24: Because `<=` will continue to the value of `str.length`, whereas `<` will stop just *before* the value of `str.length`.  Since `str.length` is always 1 greater than the last index of `str`, you want to stop iterating the loop before that value.

Comment: @VSG24 And btw, that's basically the same in C. There you also have to stop before you reach the length.

Comment: @VSG24 If you start with 1, then in the loop you need to access the array elements as `arr[i-1]` instead of as `arr[i]`. Then you'll be fine too.

Comment: @VSG24: Sure... you *could* do that.  But then the indexer in the loop block would always need a `-1` after it.  When a line of code isn't working it's usually better to fix that line than to break another line to match it.

Answer (score 1):

Because an array starts at index 0, `i` can never be the same as `str.length` because the index in the array for the value of `str.length`doesn't exist, its always one smaller, thats why you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
for(i = 0;i <= str.length;i++) {
    System.out.printf("%c\n", str[i]);
}
```

This should be

```
for(i = 0;i < str.length;i++) {
    System.out.printf("%c\n", str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Using an enhanced for loop, this should be easy:

```
for(String string:str){
 System.out.printf("%c\n", string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
    for (i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    }
```

You are iterating beyond the bound of the array.
If the length is 6, this will visit `str[0]`, `str[1]`, ..., `str[6]`,
so 7 elements, but you only have 6.
This wouldn't work in C either.

The fix is to change the `<=` to strict `<`, because you don't want to visit the `str.length`-th element:

```
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    }
```

Even better,
use the enhanced for loop syntax:

```
    for (char c : str) {
        System.out.printf("%c\n", c);
    }
```

This way there can be no more mixup with the array index.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, you're trying to access an index greater than the last index of the string.

For future reference, please notice that the exception tells you what line it occurs at (26), and has a name [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) which at face value describes the error, but can be used with Javadoc to get even more information about that error.

If you put a debugger breakpoint at line 26 in your IDE, you will then be able to see exactly what value is causing the exception.